# How many bit strings of length $10$ contain at least three $1$'s and at least three $0$'s?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The given answer is ${10 \choose 3}+{10 \choose 4}+{10 \choose 5}+{10 \choose 6}+{10 \choose 7}=912$. Why can't it be $2^4=16$ instead?

I thought that the way to solve the above question might be similar to the question below:

There are 4 choices ${G,U,A,C}$ for each element. How many $6$-element sequences ending with $GU$ can we form?

The answer is $4^4=256$.

Comment: Please use MathJax and full words when posting on MSE.

Comment: If you you were told which positions the thee $1$ and the the three $0$ were that'd be the correct way but we weren't told anything like "the first six characters are 1100101$" so that just isn't how to do it at all.

Comment: An equivalent type question is if you have 4 choices G,U,A,C how many six element sequence containing at least one G (but we don't know where) and one U (but we don't know where) are there.  The answer is *NOT* $4^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution ($2^4$) is that you are assuming that the three  $0$s and the three $1$s that are required will occupy the same position in every valid string. For example,

$$1\;0\;\_\;\_\;0\;1\;1\;\_\;0\;\_$$

The four underscores represent the positions that are free to take $1$ or $0$. But that's not correct, for two reasons.

**One**, the six *fixed* digits can switch positions among themselves. One such rearrangement of the string shown above is

$$0\;1\;\_\;\_\;0\;1\;1\;\_\;0\;\_$$

You could account for this by multiplying by $\dfrac{6!}{3! \cdot 3!}$.

**Two**, those six *fixed* digits are not required to always be in the same position. Again, for example, we could have

$$\_\;\_\;1\;0\;0\;1\;1\;\_\;0\;\_$$

I don't see how we can compensate for this. If we just multiply by $10 \choose 6$, that will lead to double counting.

Answer (score 2):

$2^4=16$ counts the strings that begin $000111$ because the last four numbers each have two choices.  There are many more ways to satisfy the requirement of three $0$s and three $1$s, like $0000011111$.  You haven't counted this one, for example.  Note in your second question the last two positions are determined, not the number of occurrences of $G,U$.  We would not count $GUACAC$ in the second.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint towards a solution, notice the two following facts.  Firstly, notice that such a string either has $0,1, ..., 10$ ones, ie. these outcomes are exclusive.  Furthermore, if a string has-- for example-- $3$ ones then it must have at least $3$ zeroes (in fact, it has $7$ of them).  Consequently, the number of outcomes we want to count is precisely the same as the number of strings in $0,1$ of length $10$ which can be written such that there are at least $3$ ones occurring, but no more than $7$ ones (otherwise we would be including strings which have less than $3$ zeroes).  Hence, if $s_n$ is the number of length $10$ strings in $0,1$ with exactly $n$ ones, then the number we are trying to calculate is $s_3 + ... +s_7$.  Now, the only task is to calculate $s_n$. The second fact regards calculating this number.  My task to you is to try and understand why $s_n = C(10, n)$.